# Are step functions monotonic functions?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title says, I'm curious if step functions are monotonic.

My understanding of "monotonic" functions is:

- For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x < y$ then $f(x) \le f(y)$ or $f(x) \ge f(y)$

Basically, I understand monotonic functions to never change the sign of their derivative.

But step functions have derivative of $0$ and so there is no sign to change.

Comment: Be careful in your bullet: the "or" is written in a slightly wrong way (it should be "For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x < y$ then $f(x) \le f(y)$, or for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x < y$ then  $f(x) \ge f(y)$").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how many 'steps' the function have.

Any one-step function is monotonic, but for more than one step it does not have to be so. For example

$$f(x) = \left\{\matrix{0 & x<0\\1 & 0\leq x \leq 1\\ 0 & x>1}\right.$$

is a non-monotonic step-function. The problem with your reasoning is that the derivative do not exist at the point where the step happens.

Answer (score 5):

The characterization in terms of derivatives only works for differentiable functions; the monotonicity definition is more general. In your example, for instance the derivative is not defined at the "jumps" of the step function and the "derivative-characterization" does not apply.

A step function will be monotone non-decreasing (resp. non-decreasing) if and only if the values it takes are non-decreasing (resp. non-increasing). I.e., the "plateau"'s are always going up (or always down).